# Spring security permitAll() does not work

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I have created a spring-boot application purely severed as resource server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

In my configuration class, I did the above (allow everything, just for experiment purpose). However, it still seems that all requests come to this server got 401 unauthorised error. PermitAll() does not seem to work.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.